# ¿Cómo importar múltiples archivos csv indicando las características con las que debe importar cada csv?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera importar múltiples archivos `csv` con las características del siguiente archivo:

```
MOVILING_Alcatraces <- read_csv("MOVILING_Alcatraces.csv", + col_types = cols(Media movil PM10 = col_number(), + PM10 = col_number(), PM2.5 = col_number(), + Year = col_number(), date = col_character()))
```

Sin embargo, no he podido realizarlo. He intentado con el siguiente código:

```
files2010 <- list.files(path="C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/R/Media movil/", pattern="*.csv")

myfiles<- lapply(X=files2010, FUN= function(x){read.csv(x, file = paste0(col_types = cols(Media movil PM10 = col_number(), + PM10 = col_number(), PM2.5 = col_number(), + Year = col_number(), date = col_character)})
```

Pero me sale mensaje de error.

> Error: unexpected symbol in "myfiles<- lapply(X=files2010, FUN=
>   function(x){read.csv(x, file = paste0(col_types = cols(Media movil"

Por otro lado, quisiera que la lista de salida, saliera con los nombres de la columna "site", ya que me sale con el nombre de la primera columna del archivo.

Comment: Hola @LauraR nos podrías compartir el error que te marca, ayudaría a entender que es lo que esta saliendo mal Saludos

Comment: ¡Hola Ruben! 
El error que me sale es el siguiente: `Error: unexpected symbol in "myfiles<- lapply(X=files2010, FUN= function(x){read.csv(x, file = paste0(col_types = cols(Media movil"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr que los nombres de la listas corresponda a los nombres de los archivos lo que 
se tiene que hacer es convertir el vector a una lista y asignarle nombre correspondientes a esa lista

```
library(purrr)

#URL donde se encuentran los archivos 
url_archivos<-"C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/R/Media movil/"

#Traemos solo los archivos que nos interesan 
files2010 <-list.files(path=url_archivos,pattern="*.csv"))

#Convertimos el archivo de files a una lista para mantener los nombres al
#leer los archivos
files2010_list<-as.list(files2010) 

#esta parte es importante ya que asignamos el nombre de la lista en base a los 
#archivos a leer
names(files2010_list)<-files2010

#leemos los archivos
 archivos <- map(files2010_list, function(x) { 
                  read_csv(paste(url_archivos,x,sep=""), 
                           col_types = cols(`Media movil PM10` = 
                           col_number(),
                           PM10 = col_number(), 
                          `PM2.5` = col_number(), 
                           Year = col_number(),
                           date = col_character()))
               })
```

Esto tendría que solucionar el problema si quisieras que al momento de leerlos los 
 una todos en un data.frame podrías usar la función map_df y utilizando parámetro id 
 dentro de esta función para saber que datos pertenecen a cada archivo

Comment: ¡Hola Ruben! Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta.He puesto el código que me has recomendado y sí me genera una lista con los nombres, pero no me deja ver cada elemento de la lista, es como si hubiera generado una lista de solo nombres, pues cada elemento sale como "character". En el código final me sale el siguiente error: `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : 
  el argumento ".f" está ausente, sin valor por omisión` ¿Sabes a qué se puede deber, o qué estoy haciendo mal? ¡Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Hola , una ves que ejecutas `names(files2010_list)<-files2010` ,  y ejecutas el cogido de `names(files2010_list)`  que es lo que despliega?

Comment: Inicialmente me genera un "Value" que dice ~chr [1:82] "MOVILING_Aeropuerto.csv","... " y luego me genera un "data" con la lista de los 82 nombres , pero cada elemento de la lista está vacío, solo me genera la lista con los nombres. El último código no me lo ejecuta por error.

Comment: Eh encontrado el error , modifique ya la respuesta el error en  `map(X=files2010_list, function(x) ...)` , cuando solo se tenia que poner  `map(files2010_list, function(x) ...)`, utiliza nuevamente el código modificado en la respuesta debe de funcionar correctamente

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Ruben! Ya me ha funcionado!

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tu idea es algo así:

```
myfiles <- lapply(X=files2010, 
                  FUN = function(x) { 
                                      read_csv(file = x, 
                                               col_types = cols(`Media movil PM10` = col_number(),
                                                                PM10 = col_number(), 
                                                                `PM2.5` = col_number(), 
                                                                Year = col_number(),
                                                                date = col_character()))
                   })
```

Veamos:

- La función es `read_csv()` no `read.csv()`, está última es una función base y no posee el parámetro `col_types`
- En este caso, como `lapply` itera sobre un vector con nombres de archivo, `x` es justamente un nombre de archivo, por lo que lo correcto es hacer `file = x`
- El uso de `paste0` nada tiene hacer aquí.
- Los nombres de las variables no son del todo "amigables", te recomiendo que normalices los mismos, sin embargo, para nombres inconsistentes puedes usar el "backtick" para encerrar los nombres.

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias Patricio! Aunque me sale el siguiente mensaje de error: `Warning: 1490 parsing failures.
 row col           expected actual                           file
1093 PST 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE  181.0 'MOVILING_zipaquiraemafez.csv'
1107 PST 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE  240.0 'MOVILING_zipaquiraemafez.csv'
1116 PST 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE  205.0 'MOVILING_zipaquiraemafez.csv'
1124 PST 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE  329.0 'MOVILING_zipaquiraemafez.csv'
1136 PST 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE  112.0 'MOVILING_zipaquiraemafez.csv'

See problems(...) for more details`  En varios de los elementos de la lista

Comment: Sin embargo, si me generó la lista, muchas gracias. ¿De casualidad sabes cómo podría hacer para que los nombres de la lista correspondan a los nombres de los archivos original en csv? Ya que me genera la lista con nombres 1,2,3 y así.

Comment: El error que mencionas es que los datos que aparecen en las columnas son de diferente tipo del cual estar mencionando  y los esta convirtiendo a NA